# php filter phrase

Tags: php, filter

How to filter `phrase` use php? Can anyone give me a function call?

for example, If I want filter the phrase 'no' 'this' from a sentence `There are no user contributed notes for this page.`

So that the sentence return like `There are user contributed notes for page.` Thanks.

```
<?php
function filterBadWords($str)
{
    $badwords = array('no','this');
    $replacements = " ";
    foreach ($badwords AS $badword)
    {
          $str = eregi_replace($badword, str_repeat(' ', strlen($badword)), $str);
    }  
    return $str;
} 

$string = "There are user contributed notes for page.";
print filterBadWords($string); // this will filter `no` from `notes`
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\b(?:no|this)\b ?/i', '', $text);
```

Edit:

Now it removes a space if it finds one after the word, so that you don't end up with two spaces in a row.

```
$text = 'There are no user contributed notes for this page.';
$text = preg_replace('/\b(?:no|this)\b ?/i', '', $text);
echo $text;
```

Outputs: There are user contributed notes for page.

**Update**

If you want to use an array to make it easier to manage filtered words you could do this:

```
function filterWords($string){
    $bad_words = array('no', 'this');
    return preg_replace('/\b(?:'.implode('|', $bad_words).')\b ?/i', '', $string);
}

echo filterWords('There are no user contributed notes for this page.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
str_replace(array('no', 'this'), '', $text);
```

Comment: `echo str_replace(array('no', 'this'), '', 'There are no user contributed notes for this page.');//There are user contributed tes for page.  ` always broke `notes` and become `tes`